# Is there any way to construct an array of methods/lambda expressions?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, lambda

I'm curious as to whether any of these is possible:

```
<something>[] methods = { method1, method2, ... }
<something>[] lambdas = { ()-><code>, ()-><code>, ... }
```

I think that in C/C++ you can define a typedef for a homogeneous class of functions, and then use the typedef to create an array of function references. Not sure, but I think that this is possible. Can this be done in Java?

Given the above definition, I would like to do something like this at runtime:

```
methods[i](); // or
lambdas[i]();
```

And I would like to include parameters if that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just figure out the type of the function (refer to the [`java.util.function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) package) and make a list of those.

For example, you can have a list of consumers `List<Consumer<String>>`, which are the lambdas that take a single input and return no result. An example of a `Consumer<String>` might be something like `x -> System.out.println("Hello, " + x)`

Answer (score 1):

You can declare collections of lambda, and call each lambda with arguments (as appropriate) in the usual manner from whatever collection you use.

For example an array of `Runnable`:

```
Runnable[] runables = new Runnable[] {
                            () -> System.out.println("Hello"),
                            System.out::println,
                            () -> System.out.println("World") };

runables[1].run();
for(var r : runables) {
    r.run();
}
```

List of `Predicate`:

```
    List<Predicate<String>> tests = List.of(s -> "Hello".equals(s), String::isEmpty);

    System.out.println(tests.get(0).test("Hello"));
    System.out.println(tests.get(0).test("World"));
    System.out.println(tests.get(1).test(""));
    System.out.println(tests.get(1).test("World"));
```

Answer (score -1):

If what you want is to store list of methods, maybe as a commands menu, you may create an interface (with all required methods), and a base class to implement the interface.

Then let several child classes extend the base class and you can store instances from all the child classes in an array as list of commands to call. The use of base class will ensure each instance have the default method to be called, even if not being override by the child class.

```
interface CommandAPI {
    public void op();
}

class Command implements CommandAPI {
    public void op() {}   // default method
}

class A extends Command {
    @Override
    public void op() {}
}

class B extends Command {
    @Override
    public void op() {}
}

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Command[] list = { new A(), new B() };
        //...
        list[0].op();
        list[1].op();
    }
}
```

Even can support named parameterized command.

```
 interface CommandAPI {
    public void cmd();
 }
    
 class Command implements CommandAPI {
    public void cmd() {}   // default method
 }
    
 class A extends Command {
    public int param;
    @Override
    public void cmd() { /* do something with param */ }
 }
    
 class B extends Command {
    public int param1;
    public String param2;
    @Override
    public void cmd() {  /* do something with param 1 and 2 */ }
 }
    
 public class FuncPtr {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Command[] list = { new A(), new B() };
        //...
              
        if(list[0] instanceof A) {
            ( (A) list[0] ).param = 1;
        }
        list[0].cmd();

        if(list[1] instanceof B) {
            ( (B) list[1] ).param1 = 100;
            ( (B) list[1] ).param2 = "Hello";
        }
        list[1].cmd();
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But what I'm interested in is something like array<???> a = {()->funct and/or (arglist)->funct}. The method you suggested will work and is general, in the sense that the argument list can be heterogeneous (with some care). But I wondered whether it I could bypass creating a class containing the function(s) of choice. One usage is, as you suggested, to have a command list and/or to build an interpreter (converting commands to integers), and their are probably dozens of other uses.